# WSS3 SP2 Search cannot find list item by number column

Tags: sharepoint, list, search, wss-3.0-sp2

When I add a new column to a list in WSS3 (SP2, note: not MOSS), the search feature cannot find items by the values in those columns.

What I've done:

- Added an issues list (built in)
- Added a column called customid of type number to the list
- Added a column called customref of type text (single line) to the list

When I add items, the search feature detects them (after indexing is run) by the title, Issue ID (built in), and customref. However, when I search by the customid, it returns no results.

I cannot find any documentation online which indicates that this is a limitation of WSS3.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Your time is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically you would have to create a managed property to achieve the functionality you are looking for but i'm afraid that you can not achieve in WSS alternatively you can use search server which is also a free you can find more details about search server at following links

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183108(v=Office.12).aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc297193(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Thanks Ashutosh. I was unable to find any documentation from Microsoft indicating that lists are not fully searchable using WSS3. Do you know where I might be able to find such a thing?